# R - Font recognised when used for the title, but not recognised when used in mtext

Tags: r

I have spent ages trying to work out how to use Futura in R. 
for some reason I dont understand, when I use this code:

title('Months', family='Futura')
mtext('writing', family= 'Futura')

the title is in Futura, but the mtext doesnt show up (i.e. futura is not recognised). 
I have not loaded any specific packages so I do not even understand why the title is showing in the correct font. 
Any advice would be appreciated!